# How to paste a list into a multi index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, multi-index

Could you let me know how to paste a list into a multi-index dataframe?

I wanna paste list1 into column([func1 - In - Name1, Name2]['Val6'])

and  list2 into column([func1 - Out - Name3, Name4]['Val6']) in multi-index dataframe

below is dataframe I used

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
raw_data = {'Function': ['env', 'env', 'env', 'func1', 'func1', 'func1'],
            'Type': ['In', 'In', 'In', 'In','In', 'out'],
            'Name': ['Volt', 'Temp', 'BD#', 'Name1','Name2', 'Name3'],
            'Val1': ['Max', 'High', '1', '3', '5', '6'],
            'Val2': ['Typ', 'Mid', '2', '4', '7', '6'],
            'Val3': ['Min', 'Low', '3', '3', '6', '3'],
            'Val4': ['Max', 'High', '4', '3', '9', '4'],
            'Val5': ['Max', 'Low', '5', '3', '4', '5'] }
df = DataFrame(raw_data)
df= df.set_index(["Function", "Type","Name"])
df['Val6'] = np.NaN

list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [3,4]

print (df)
```

below is printed dataframe

```
                     Val1 Val2 Val3  Val4 Val5  Val6
Function Type Name                                  
env      In   Volt    Max  Typ  Min   Max  Max   NaN
              Temp   High  Mid  Low  High  Low   NaN
              BD#       1    2    3     4    5   NaN
func1    In   Name1     4    2    3     4    5   NaN
              Name2     6    7    6     9    4   NaN
         out  Name3     6    6    3     4    5   NaN
              Name4     3    3    4     5    6   NaN
```

Below is expected results. 
I'd like to sequentially put each list1 and list2 into dataframe  instead of NaN like below

```
                         Val1 Val2 Val3  Val4 Val5  Val6
    Function Type Name                                  
    env      In   Volt    Max  Typ  Min   Max  Max   NaN
                  Temp   High  Mid  Low  High  Low   NaN
                  BD#       1    2    3     4    5   NaN
    func1    In   Name1     4    2    3     4    5     1
                  Name2     6    7    6     9    4     2
             out  Name3     6    6    3     4    5     3
                  Name4     3    3    4     5    6     4
```

I have tried to use concat, replace functions to do it but failed

In more complex datafrmae, I think it is better to use mask of multi -index in dataframe.

```
list1=[1,2]
list2=[3,4]
m1 = df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'func1'
m2 = df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'In'

list1 = [float(i) for i in list1]
df_list1=pd.DataFrame(list1)

df.replace(df[m1&m2]['Val6'], df_list1)
```

Unfortunately, I don't have any idea to solve the problem. T_T

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC add an extra line at the end, simple modify it like it's a non-multi-index dataframe:

```
df['Val6'] = df['Val6'].tolist()[:-4] + list1 + list2
```

So your code would be:

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
raw_data = {'Function': ['env', 'env', 'env', 'func1', 'func1', 'func1'],
            'Type': ['In', 'In', 'In', 'In','In', 'out'],
            'Name': ['Volt', 'Temp', 'BD#', 'Name1','Name2', 'Name3'],
            'Val1': ['Max', 'High', '1', '3', '5', '6'],
            'Val2': ['Typ', 'Mid', '2', '4', '7', '6'],
            'Val3': ['Min', 'Low', '3', '3', '6', '3'],
            'Val4': ['Max', 'High', '4', '3', '9', '4'],
            'Val5': ['Max', 'Low', '5', '3', '4', '5'] }
df = DataFrame(raw_data)
df= df.set_index(["Function", "Type","Name"])
df['Val6'] = np.NaN

list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [3,4]

df['Val6'] = df['Val6'].tolist()[:-4] + list1 + list2

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                     Val1 Val2 Val3  Val4 Val5  Val6
Function Type Name                                  
env      In   Volt    Max  Typ  Min   Max  Max   NaN
              Temp   High  Mid  Low  High  Low   NaN
              BD#       1    2    3     4    5   1.0
func1    In   Name1     3    4    3     3    3   2.0
              Name2     5    7    6     9    4   3.0
         out  Name3     6    6    3     4    5   4.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's good solution. In more complex dataframe, I think it is better to use mask of multi -index in dataframe. Unfortunately, I don't have any idea to  solve the problem. T_T

Comment: I also think it over more. Thanks